# Implementing dependency across a dynamic number of radio button groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have the following code.

```html
10:00 - 10:30:  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Science"> Science <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Math"> Math<br>
10:30 - 11:00:  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Science"> Science <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Math"> Math<br>
```

So how can I make it where if someone presses Science for the first time then they can't click it again for the second?

Edit:

Is there a way where the JS/Jquery code can be done without being dependent on the number of groups as the number of groups are dependent?

Comment: You have already accepted an answer. If you did not intend to, you should have waited for the other user to undelete and accept that instead.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I already accepted this answer, then the other user posted his answer which I felt was more like what I needed and the other one is a little bit more scalable. We were commenting on his answer and he said he will try to fix a mistake he found in his answer as you should be able to see in the comments of that. So I was waiting till he fixed it so I could accept his answer as well. If he was unable to fix his code, I still want it so I have something to try to develop on top of, Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What I mean is once he fixed the answer I was going to select his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing as you asked for javascript but other answers are in jquery:

Given the html:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Science" onclick="clickAction();"> Science <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Math" onclick="clickAction();"> Math<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Science"> Science <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Math"> Math<br>
```

Pure Javascript:

```
function clickAction() {
var sel = document.querySelector('input[name="group1"]:checked').value;
var grp2 = document.getElementsByName('group2');
  for(var i = 0; i < grp2.length; i++) {
    if(grp2[i].value == sel){
      grp2[i].disabled = true;
      grp2[i].checked = false;
    } else {
     grp2[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

What you will want to do is set an onclick call inline for each item in the first group. When that function is called you will want to grab the selected value from the first group then iterate through your second list (get a collection of elements by their group name) and compare the values. If the value match then you need to add the disabled attribute and also unselect it if it is already selected. If is does not match then you need to set the disabled attribute to false in order to re-enable it (or keep it current).

jsfiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/s4qjfmuz/1/

Also keep in mind that your function needs to be available to be called, in this fiddler example I have it loading in the head.

If your requirements allow jquery then this becomes even easier.

Edit: Based on new requirements of X number of radio groups can be generated AND your ability to use JQuery, here is a new sample (please see comments in jquery for explanation of workflow):

New Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/rqmr2jdz/

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Science" class="childRadio"> Science <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Math" class="childRadio"> Math <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Social Studies" class="childRadio"> Social Studies <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Chemistry" class="childRadio"> Chemistry<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Science" class="childRadio"> Science <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Math" class="childRadio"> Math <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Social Studies" class="childRadio"> Social Studies <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Chemistry" class="childRadio"> Chemistry<br>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="Science" class="childRadio"> Science <input type="radio" name="group3" value="Math" class="childRadio"> Math <input type="radio" name="group3" value="Social Studies" class="childRadio"> Social Studies <input type="radio" name="group3" value="Chemistry" class="childRadio"> Chemistry<br>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".childRadio").change(function() {
    //Get the ele that triggered the change
    var selObj = this;
    //Get current list of selected item values for later use
    var alReadySelArray = []; 
    $('.childRadio:checked').each(function() {
      //pusinbg to array
      alReadySelArray.push($(this).val());
    });
    //Iterate through elements and decide how to handle with new change
    $(".childRadio").each(function() {
      //if not the current object that was selected
      if(selObj !== this){
        //if the value isn't already selected somehwere then it should be available
        if (($.inArray($(this).val(), alReadySelArray) === -1)){
          $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          //Else disable all except the one already checked
          if($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
          }
        }
      } 
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I am pretty new to programming, could you show me an example?

Comment: @Riz-waan I've modified my answer to show an example using pure javascript as you made no mention of jquery being available in your question.

Comment: I can use jquery if this becomes easier but here in this fiddle I have added two more groups, https://jsfiddle.net/x4h2s5k0/ Is there a way to do keep the same javascript code no matter how many groups I add with something like the class attribute? Is there a way using Jquery as eithier will work?

Comment: The purpose of this is to get a n number of groups from a sql database and I think it would be easier if the jquery/javascript code is not based off of the number of groups but is rather independent. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Riz-waan update posted to handle situation described. Please also update your original question all the details so other users may find it helpful when searching for their answer. This will be my last edit as you have already chosen a different selected answer but I hope this helps you find your way to a resolution.

Comment: Also last kind request if possible do you know how I could unselect radio buttons where as if one changed his mind on the classes? And since I have selected your answer I hope you could do one more edit, Thank you

Comment: @Riz-waan See update https://jsfiddle.net/rqmr2jdz/1/  

What this does is define a div class for each group and set it to hidden to act as a remove button. When an item is selected it builds the div name based upon the group name of the selected element and sets it to true. The actual div has a onclick function attached that will remove the selected item from it's group then rehide itself. There may be a more elegant way to do this than shown but this will give you an option to start thinking about different ways to implemement a reset.

Comment: Is there a way to use something else other than the name and value attribute? like can I do it using the id attribute?

Comment: Or using another class?

Comment: Or using the data attribute, I feel like the data attribute could make the code cleaner.

Comment: I can't use the id attribute as it is recommended to be all different.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you will need to write some JavaScript code that runs on the client side.

For example, here is a sample using the jQuery library:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var foo = document.getElementById('sci1').checked;
  var foo2 = document.getElementById('math1').checked;
  
  if (foo == true) {
    jQuery("#sci2").attr('disabled', true);
     document.getElementById('sci2').checked=false;
  } else {
  jQuery("#sci2").attr('disabled', false);
  }
   if (foo2 == true) {
    jQuery("#math2").attr('disabled', true);
    document.getElementById('math2').checked=false;
    
  } else {
  jQuery("#math2").attr('disabled', false);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
10:00 - 10:30:  <input type="radio" id="sci1" name="group1" value="Science"> Science <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="math1" value="Math"> Math<br>
10:30 - 11:00:  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Science"  id="sci2"> Science <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Math" id="math2"> Math<br>
```